# Book a batch of meetings in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

One of my smaller clients doesn't have any kind of central software update mechanisms (like SCCM) so I occasionally have to book individual meetings with 30+ users. Doing this manually is tedious to say the least!

Is there is a way to this a) in Outlook or b) with the aid of a 3rd party tool? Basically the functionality would be to supply a list of names/email addresses, a template for the email invite and it finds free slots and fires off the invite.

Not even sure what to Google to find suitable tools/helpers.

I'm pretty adept at VBA so might even look if I can do something via Macros if the above draws a blank.

Can't believe I'm the only person who needs this kind of functionality.

Comment: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-appointments-spreadsheet-data/ this may be useful

Comment: Thanks for that - even if I can't use it as is it does give me a big step up in terms of the API calls needed